# Error 0xc00d36c4 in Windows 10 Media player when playing video

Tags: error-handling, camera, windows-10, video-capture

I've recorded a video with my logitech webcam C920 and a hooked up MXL Microphone MXL Conferencing AC-404 on my laptop. I used the app Camera by default in Windows 10 to record it.

After it was done, everything seems fine and when I play the video it gives me Error 0xc00d36c4. The video is like 7gb and just before recording I tested the material and it was working fine and the previous video was playing.

It's a very important video for work and just can't get it to work.
Any ideas or solutions you guys have?

I've tried Stellar Video Recovery but not much luck, I could get like 45 mins of images but no sounds.

Thanks

Comment: c00d36c4 = MF_E_UNSUPPORTED_BYTESTREAM_TYPE = The byte stream type of the given URL is unsupported which video codec have you used?

Comment: I think it's MPEG-4

Comment: try other video playback program

Comment: I tried VLC, K-Lite Media Codec with classic media player, still nothing